# is there a way to set the title and author metadata properties of a pdf in python?

Tags: python, pdf, metadata, title, author

I need to create numerous ADA-compliant pdfs from word documents. I used a code snippet from comtypes.client which works very well to create a pdf, but when i run the accessibility checker on the PDF, it gives a Title FAIL, and it has my name as the author rather than my organization's name. Is there any way to set the title and author while making the PDF or alternatively, after it is finished? I would prefer to use python, but if there are any other simpler methods out there, I am game.

I have looked at PyPDF2, but it seems to only set 'custom metadata' rather than actually change or set title/author properties. (plus the code snippet I tried from the web kept returning an error - i am not pasting the code though as i dont think it does what i need anyways..)

I cannot tell if something like pdftk does what i need or not...i cant find anyway to do it with the free version, and i see this example https://sejh.wordpress.com/2014/11/26/changing-pdf-titles-with-pdftk/, but at best it looks like it might work for title but not author, and i am not sure if there is an easy way to run the script for many pdfs...

Ive also looked into EXIF, which seems to only read pdfs, but points to XMP as a way to write the metadata... only after resurfacing from an extensive XMP rabbit-hole i went down, i still cant tell if it would be useful or not.

so i thought i would try here. see if anyone has a nice, easy python solution, or if not, can point me to a rabbit hole worth going down, and any hints on how to navigate said rabbit-holes to find an answer.

Much appreciated!

Comment: As a side note, it is normally the document title and the flag setting to display the title in the application title bar that is required for ADA. It is not the author

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

i was able to solve my issue at the Word document stage by using the core_properties attribute in Python's docx (I had not been aware of this attribute at the time of my original post).

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document()
cp = doc.core_properties
cp.author = 'author name'                
cp.title = 'title content'
cp.subject = 'subject content'
```

when I then used Python's comtypes to pdf the Word doc, the metadata transferred successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The general reason for you as Author is "Machine User is the Author even if that is your secretary" so easiest is run a PDF app in an "Organisation" login, but as you point out pdftk allows you to make changes, so stick with that. Use Python to write the needful change in NewInfo.txt then shell out to run pdftk.

[image]

```
InfoBegin
InfoKey: Creator
InfoValue: Stack OverFlow
InfoBegin
InfoKey: Producer
InfoValue: Status Quo
InfoBegin
InfoKey: Author
InfoValue: K Steinmann
InfoBegin
InfoKey: Title
InfoValue: Whatever You Want, Whatever You Need, dah dah dah...
```

`pdftk input.pdf update_info NewInfo.txt output output.pdf`

Comment: thank you - i think i may have found an option at the Word doc stage using Python's docx - i hadnt realized they had a module to set documentation properties. So far it seems those properties transfer through to the pdf once it is created. Appreciate your suggestion though - maybe useful in the future for me